# How Fiting and evaluate model in pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I 'm newer in Pytorch,
I worked with keras, so I write:

```
history = model.fit(training_set, steps_per_epoch=2020 // 16,
        epochs=100,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=862 // 16,
        callbacks=[early_stop, reduce_lr])



###Evaluation
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_set, verbose=0)
print('loss={}, accuracy={}'.format(loss, accuracy))
```

So how can I transform this bloc in Pytorch
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In pytorch, there is no fit method or evaluate method, normally you need to define the custom training loop and your evaluate function manually. So it's basically quite low lever.
If you really need the fit method, you can use pytorch lightning, which is a high lever wrapper of pytorch.
There are plenty of video tutorials on youtube, I recommend you watch some to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete so we can't give a exact answer. However, I just give you a rough sample of how to proceed. Loop is typically written manually instead of using the `fit()`. something like this:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

model = MyModel()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

train_loader = DataLoader(training_set, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=16, shuffle=False)

# Train the model
for epoch in range(100):
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs, labels = data

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 100 == 99:
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' % (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 100))
            running_loss = 0.0

    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in test_loader:
            inputs, labels = data
            outputs = model(inputs)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    print('Accuracy of the network on the test set: %d %%' % (100 * correct / total))
```